# Angular - Retrieval of Variable from Async Code (RxJs)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Apologies if this has been asked somewhere, as I am very new to RxJs and still learning the ropes, I have a small piece of code where I need to return **True** or **False** based on some conditions that we retrieve using RxJs. First of all, here is the code,

```
private getStatus(): boolean {
    this.subs.add(
      this.coverable$?.subscribe((coverable) => {
        this.classOfUse = coverable.classOfUse;
      })
    );
    return (
      this.userEnabled &&
      (this.classOfUse === 'Personal' || this.classOfUse === 'Leisure')
    );
  }
```

So, what I am doing here is, retrieving **classOfUse** and then just doing a simple check and returning value back. **userEnabled** is something that is defined globally and is being accessed here.

So my **QUESTION** is, I've been told the following about this,

*You can't use variable that you've retrieved in async code like that. What if the coverable subscription doesn't return class of use before this piece of code (return functionality) is executed?*

Can anyone please tell what I'm doing wrong here or if there is a better way of doing this? Thank you and looking forward to your help

Comment: Do you know about ‘BehaviourSubject’?

Comment: Unfortunately ... No

Comment: Could you tell where you will use result of the getStatus() function?

Answer (score 1):

There is not much clarity on what you are trying to achieve but I will try to answer your question. Normally you should call getStatus() inside ngOnInit() and bind the **flag** variable on the html side

```
flag = false
private getStatus() {
    this.subs.add(
      this.coverable$?.subscribe((coverable) => {
        this.classOfUse = coverable.classOfUse;
        this.flag = this.userEnabled && (this.classOfUse === 'Personal' || this.classOfUse === 'Leisure')
      })
    );
  }
```

The issue here will be unless the API call is complete the class will not get applied. If that logic works for you then it's fine. But if you want this data to be retrieved before your template is loaded in that case you need [Angular Resolver](https://www.bacancytechnology.com/blog/angular-resolver)

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to solve your issue

1. Use a class variable

TS

```
class SomeClass {
  status: boolean
  ngOnLoad() {
    this.getStatus()
  }

  private getStatus() {
    this.subs.add(
      this.coverable$?.subscribe((coverable) => {
       this.status = this.userEnabled &&
          (coverable.classOfUse === 'Personal' || coverable.classOfUse === 'Leisure')
      })
    );
  }
}
```

HTML

```html
{{status}}
```

2. Use an observable in your template(it depends on your needs) with the map.
   It will refresh only when coverable$ is updated(if this.userEnabled is udpated, the status$ observable will not give a new value)

TS

```
class SomeClass {

  getStatus$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.coverable$.pipe(
      map((coverable) => {
        return (
          this.userEnabled &&
          (coverable.classOfUse === 'Personal' ||
            coverable.classOfUse === 'Leisure')
        );
      })
    );
  }
}
```

HTML

```
{{getStatus$() | async}}
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mosvj4?file=src/main.ts

3. Get userEnabled as Observable(if this's possible) and use combineLatest. More proper way.

TS

```
class SomeClass {

  getStatus$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return combineLatest([this.coverable$, this.userEnabled$]).pipe(
      map(([coverable, userEnabled]) => {
        return (
          userEnabled &&
          (coverable.classOfUse === 'Personal' ||
            coverable.classOfUse === 'Leisure')
        );
      })
    );
  }
}
```

HTML

```
{{getStatus$() | async}}
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tvuwog?file=src/main.ts